# Error when installing json gem for ruby 2.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, macos, rubygems

I'm running ruby 2.0.0p0 on Mac OSX 10.9 and trying to installing the gem json but keep getting an error message that it has failed to build the gem native extension.

I attempted to update the rubygems with: gem update --system but still get the same error message.

Do I need to possibly install a different version of json (other than 1.8.1) for the version of ruby I am running?

Here is the full output in case that helps to see the issue:

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing json:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /Users/aaron/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/bin/ruby extconf.rb
creating Makefile

make "DESTDIR=" clean

make "DESTDIR="
compiling generator.c
In file included from /Users/aaron/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby.h:33,
                 from ../fbuffer/fbuffer.h:5,
                 from generator.c:1:
/Users/aaron/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/ruby.h:51:21: error: string.h: No such file or directory
/Users/aaron/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/ruby.h:61:21: error: stdint.h: No such file or directory
/Users/aaron/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/ruby.h:64:23: error: inttypes.h: No such file or directory
/Users/aaron/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/ruby.h:68:19: error: stdio.h: No such file or directory
In file included from /Users/aaron/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/ruby.h:70,
                 from /Users/aaron/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby.h:33,
                 from ../fbuffer/fbuffer.h:5,
                 from generator.c:1:
/Users/aaron/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/defines.h:29:21: error: stdlib.h: No such file or directory
In file included from /Users/aaron/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/ruby.h:194,
                 from /Users/aaron/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby.h:33,
                 from ../fbuffer/fbuffer.h:5,
                 from generator.c:1:
/usr/local/Cellar/apple-gcc42/4.2.1-5666.3/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-apple-darwin11/4.2.1/include/limits.h:10:25: error: limits.h: No such file or directory
In file included from /Users/aaron/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/ruby.h:1566,
                 from /Users/aaron/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby.h:33,
                 from ../fbuffer/fbuffer.h:5,
                 from generator.c:1:
/Users/aaron/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/missing.h:23:45: error: math.h: No such file or directory
/Users/aaron/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/missing.h:29:24: error: sys/time.h: No such file or directory
/Users/aaron/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/missing.h:38:25: error: sys/types.h: No such file or directory
In file included from /Users/aaron/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/ruby.h:1566,
                 from /Users/aaron/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby.h:33,
                 from ../fbuffer/fbuffer.h:5,
                 from generator.c:1:
/Users/aaron/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/missing.h:57: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘__syscall’
In file included from /Users/aaron/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/intern.h:34,
                 from /Users/aaron/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/ruby.h:1567,
                 from /Users/aaron/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby.h:33,
                 from ../fbuffer/fbuffer.h:5,
                 from generator.c:1:
/Users/aaron/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/st.h:140: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘uint32_t’
In file included from /Users/aaron/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/ruby.h:1567,
                 from /Users/aaron/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby.h:33,
                 from ../fbuffer/fbuffer.h:5,
                 from generator.c:1:
/Users/aaron/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/intern.h:318: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘rb_fdset_t’
/Users/aaron/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/intern.h:407: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘fd_set’
/Users/aaron/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/intern.h:407: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘fd_set’
/Users/aaron/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/intern.h:407: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘fd_set’
/Users/aaron/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/intern.h:407: warning: ‘struct timeval’ declared inside parameter list
/Users/aaron/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/intern.h:407: warning: its scope is only this definition or declaration, which is probably not what you want
/Users/aaron/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/intern.h:408: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘rb_fdset_t’
/Users/aaron/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/intern.h:408: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘rb_fdset_t’
/Users/aaron/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/intern.h:408: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘rb_fdset_t’
/Users/aaron/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/intern.h:408: warning: ‘struct timeval’ declared inside parameter list
/Users/aaron/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/intern.h:409: warning: ‘struct timeval’ declared inside parameter list
/Users/aaron/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/intern.h:505: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘mode_t’
/Users/aaron/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/intern.h:584: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘pid_t’
/Users/aaron/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/intern.h:598: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘rb_fork’
/Users/aaron/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/intern.h:599: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘rb_fork_err’
/Users/aaron/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/intern.h:601: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘rb_waitpid’
/Users/aaron/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/intern.h:602: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘pid’
/Users/aaron/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/intern.h:603: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘rb_spawn’
/Users/aaron/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/intern.h:604: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘rb_spawn_err’
/Users/aaron/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/intern.h:606: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘pid’
/Users/aaron/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/intern.h:719: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘uint32_t’
/Users/aaron/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/intern.h:842: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘long’
/Users/aaron/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/intern.h:843: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘long’
In file included from generator.c:1:
../fbuffer/fbuffer.h: In function ‘fbuffer_alloc’:
../fbuffer/fbuffer.h:72: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘memset’
../fbuffer/fbuffer.h:72: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘memset’
../fbuffer/fbuffer.h: In function ‘fbuffer_append’:
../fbuffer/fbuffer.h:109: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘memcpy’
../fbuffer/fbuffer.h:109: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘memcpy’
In file included from generator.c:2:
generator.h:6:19: error: ctype.h: No such file or directory
generator.c: In function ‘fstrndup’:
generator.c:304: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘memccpy’
generator.c: At top level:
generator.c:380: warning: unused parameter ‘self’
generator.c: In function ‘mString_to_json_raw_object’:
generator.c:410: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘strlen’
generator.c:410: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘strlen’
generator.c:411: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘strlen’
generator.c: In function ‘mString_Extend_json_create’:
generator.c:438: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘strlen’
generator.c:439: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘strlen’
generator.c: At top level:
generator.c:434: warning: unused parameter ‘self’
generator.c: In function ‘State_allocate’:
generator.c:505: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘memset’
generator.c: In function ‘set_state_ivars’:
generator.c:611: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘strlen’
generator.c: In function ‘cState_aref’:
generator.c:657: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘strlen’
generator.c: In function ‘cState_aset’:
generator.c:671: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘strlen’
generator.c:675: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘strlen’
generator.c: At top level:
generator.c:767: warning: unused parameter ‘Vstate’
generator.c:781: warning: unused parameter ‘Vstate’
generator.c:781: warning: unused parameter ‘state’
generator.c:781: warning: unused parameter ‘obj’
generator.c:786: warning: unused parameter ‘Vstate’
generator.c:786: warning: unused parameter ‘state’
generator.c:786: warning: unused parameter ‘obj’
generator.c:791: warning: unused parameter ‘Vstate’
generator.c:791: warning: unused parameter ‘state’
generator.c:791: warning: unused parameter ‘obj’
generator.c:796: warning: unused parameter ‘Vstate’
generator.c:796: warning: unused parameter ‘state’
generator.c:801: warning: unused parameter ‘Vstate’
generator.c:801: warning: unused parameter ‘state’
generator.c: In function ‘generate_json_float’:
generator.c:813: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘isinf’
generator.c:816: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘isnan’
generator.c: At top level:
generator.c:807: warning: unused parameter ‘Vstate’
generator.c: In function ‘isArrayOrObject’:
generator.c:905: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘isspace’
generator.c: In function ‘cState_init_copy’:
generator.c:972: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘memcpy’
generator.c: In function ‘cState_indent’:
generator.c:1013: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘strlen’
generator.c: In function ‘cState_indent_set’:
generator.c:1035: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘strdup’
generator.c:1035: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘strdup’
generator.c: In function ‘cState_space’:
generator.c:1050: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘strlen’
generator.c: In function ‘cState_space_set’:
generator.c:1073: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘strdup’
generator.c: In function ‘cState_space_before’:
generator.c:1087: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘strlen’
generator.c: In function ‘cState_space_before_set’:
generator.c:1109: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘strdup’
generator.c: In function ‘cState_object_nl’:
generator.c:1124: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘strlen’
generator.c: In function ‘cState_object_nl_set’:
generator.c:1146: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘strdup’
generator.c: In function ‘cState_array_nl’:
generator.c:1160: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘strlen’
generator.c: In function ‘cState_array_nl_set’:
generator.c:1181: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘strdup’
generator.c: In function ‘Init_generator’:
generator.c:1402: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘strlen’
generator.c:1403: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘strlen’
generator.c:1404: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘strlen’
generator.c:1405: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘strlen’
generator.c:1406: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘strlen’
generator.c:1407: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘strlen’
generator.c:1408: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘strlen’
generator.c:1409: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘strlen’
generator.c:1410: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘strlen’
generator.c:1411: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘strlen’
generator.c:1412: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘strlen’
generator.c:1413: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘strlen’
generator.c:1414: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘strlen’
generator.c:1415: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘strlen’
generator.c:1416: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘strlen’
generator.c:1417: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘strlen’
generator.c:1418: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘strlen’
generator.c:1419: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘strlen’
generator.c:1420: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘strlen’
generator.c:1421: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘strlen’
generator.c:1422: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘strlen’
generator.c:1423: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘strlen’
generator.c:1424: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘strlen’
generator.c:1425: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘strlen’
generator.c:1426: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘strlen’
generator.c:1427: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘strlen’
generator.c:1429: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘strlen’
generator.c:1429: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘strlen’
generator.c:1430: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘strlen’
generator.c:1431: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘strlen’
generator.c:1433: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘strlen’
make: *** [generator.o] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your gemfile

```
gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby
```

Then run bundle install.

Comment: I added this to the gemfile (for json) then ran the bundle install. It fetched the meta data, resolved dependencies, etc. Then gave error "Errno::EACCES: Permission denied - json-1.8.1.gem
An error occurred while installing json (1.8.1), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install json -v '1.8.1'` succeeds before bundling."